# How does being faster help me?

Tags: kairobotica

I can use the Kairo Train bot or levelling to boost the speed of my Kairobots. Why would I want faster bots? What does this gain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the in-game help (Page 8, if you're interested):

> Legs represent the Kairobots' speed, which affects how swiftly they attack.  It also affects their ability to evade attacks and to inflict more attacks than the enemy.

So faster bots = bots that will survive longer, due to attacking (and hopefully killing) before the enemies have a chance, and getting hit less often.  Seeing as how powerful attacks can knock out several bots with one hit, evading it just allowed you to get another attack in.